# Django ModelForm. Hide models name

Tags: python, django

I have a ModelForm:

```py
class First_Form(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('text',)
    widgets = {
        'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control",
                                      "id": "exampleFormControlInput1",
                                      "placeholder": "Enter your YouTube link",
                                      "rows": 1, }), }
```

On my site it looks like:

[image: Site Ilustration]

Can I hide name of ModelForm field? - "Text"?
I want to show only InputField without "Text:"

Thank you!

Comment: It's called a "label". It seems you don't want to hide it but change it to "Email address". You shouldn't manually enter the "Email address" in your HTML. Just look for "field label" in the django docs. You can either do this in the form or in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding this:

```
labels = {
    'text': '',
}
```

or this:

```
class First_Form(forms.ModelForm):
...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(ModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['text'].label = ''
```

Comment: Great!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by two ways, one change verbose name in models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
   text = models.CharField(verbose_name="Not text", max_length=255)
```

Or override the `First_form` to add verbose name:

```
class First_Form(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('text',)
    widgets = {
        'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control",
                                      "id": "exampleFormControlInput1",
                                      "placeholder": "Enter your YouTube link",
                                      "rows": 1, }), }
    labels = {
        'text': 'Not text',
    }
```

More information can be found in this [**`documentation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types).